# Toggle reactive form controls enable or disable based on dropdown selected value

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I have a reactive form of some inputs and select element , the role is to disable or enable so input base on the value of select.

```
this.form.get('option').valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {

    if (value === 'value1') {
        this.form.get('input01').disable();
        this.form.get('input02').disable();
        this.form.get('input03').disable();
    } else {
        this.form.get('input01').enable();
        this.form.get('input02').enable();
        this.form.get('input03').enable();
    }
});
```

My form have 10 inputs like that. so I have 10 lines of code for enable and 10 lines of code for disable. I was looking for a way to refactor this code to something like `setValue` method like set all the elements of the form  to disable or enable, based on the value given in if condition, or suggest me if there is any other better way.

Thanks;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add all the associated controls under a FormGroup, and then you can just disable and enable them.
**Let say we have this HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="cForm" (submit)="submitForm(cForm.value)" novalidate>
    <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
    <br>
    <input formControlName="mainControl" type="text" name="mainControl" required />
    <div formGroupName="g1">
        <input formControlName="test" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div formGroupName="g1">
        <input formControlName="test2" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" [disabled]="!cForm.valid">
</form>
```

So we have one form which contains input and another group of two inputs, so you want to disable only the two inputs.


**Code:**

```
this.cForm = this._fb.group({
  mainControl: [
    null,
    [Validators.required])
  ],
  g1: this._fb.group({
    test: [null, [Validators.required]],
    test2: [null, [Validators.required]]
  })
});
toggle = () => {
   const control = this.cForm.get("g1");
   if (control.disabled) {
     control.enable();
   } else {
     control.disable();
   }
}
```

So when we press on the top button, it is call the toggle function and its check if the group already disabled, then it enable it, and the same for the opposite direction.

I assumed that you dont want to disable all the form controls, just a portion of inputs.
But if you do like to disable and enable the whole form, you can just get rid of the other nested group and do the same for the group.
In your case, you do the same, instead of the button toggle, your have to do it inside the subscription.

*Good luck !*

Comment: That can't work in my case I have may be different value and each value has different control to set

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to disable some form controls based on the selected value of dropdown list, my solution is to call disable / enable method base on the value like this

```
 this.form.get('input02')[value === 'testValue' ? 'enable' : 'disable']();
```

and we can short this `value === 'testValue' ? 'enable' : 'disable'` be create a cutome function

```
getState(state:boolean) : string { 
  return state ? 'enable' : disable; 
}
```

final solution

```
this.form.get('option').valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {

  this.form.get('input01')[this.getState(value === 'value1')]();
  this.form.get('input02')[this.getState(value === 'value1')]();
  this.form.get('input03')[this.getState(value === 'value1')]();

  // now I can test more cases  
  this.form.get('input04')[this.getState(value === 'value2')]();
  this.form.get('input05')[this.getState(value === 'value2')]();

  this.form.get('input06')[this.getState(value === 'value3')]();
  this.form.get('input07')[this.getState(value === 'value3')]();

})
```