# Disable an element with ElementRef

Tags: angular

I have used ElementRef for disabling an element.

//My viewchild declaration

```
   @ViewChild("txtSysId") txtSysId: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>;
```

//My Constructor Injection

```
  constructor(private _data: GetTransactionService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private transDtls: GetTransactionDtlsService, private dateform: FormatDateService, private render: Renderer2, private apiService: ApiService, private login: LoginService, private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>, private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
```

//Code for disable

```
this.txtSysId.nativeElement.disabled = false;
```

I`m using visual studio, it gives error on IDE itself as "Property disabled does not exist on HTMLElement", I`m using angular6, also disabled is available when try to do it from console with breakpoint. I`m new to angular pls help

Comment: What are you trying to disasble? Cant you use [disabled] or [attr.disabled] for that?

Comment: I have tried with [disabled]="loginSysId!=='Admin'" it didn`t work, even this [disabled]="true" didn`t work

Comment: You better show us actual markup.

Comment: <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="floating-label">
          <select class="floating-select" value="" formControlName="systemId" [disabled]="loginSysId!=='Admin'" #txtSysId disabled>
            <option *ngFor="let val of systemId" [ngValue]="val">{{val}}</option>
          </select>
          <span class="highlight"></span>
          <label>System Id</label>
        </div>
      </div>

Comment: check my question it 's has an example how to disable and enable form control element https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443127/toggle-reactive-form-controls-enable-or-disable-based-on-dropdown-selected-value @mano10

Answer (score 1):

use

```
this.myForm.get('systemId').disable();
```

to disable that controll on demand.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a reactive forms it seems, so take advantage of it.

```
this.myForm.get('myControl').disable();
this.myForm.get('myControl').enable();
```

If you don't want to use that, please post the HTML code that the `txtSysId` refers to.

Comment: Ok, but my elementRef code gives error in console sometimes, what`s that Generic type 'ElementRef<T>' requires between 0 and 1 type arguments.

Comment: It means it's either `ElementRef`, or `ElementRef<HTMLElement>`, but not `ElementRef<HTMLElement, any>`.

Comment: If I`m using ElementRef or ElementRef<HTMLElement> it shows error Generic type element ElementRef<T, any> requires 2 type arguments

Comment: Where do you import it from ?

Comment: import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef  } from '@angular/core';

Comment: Then it should work. If it doesn't, please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176565/discussion-between-mano10-and-trichetriche).